# Generic fn, channel, and thread spawn

Tags: closures, rust, lifetime

I have this code here: ([Playground link](http://is.gd/WGVOGf))

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

fn run<T: Send>(task: fn() -> T) -> T {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        tx.send(task());
    });
    rx.recv().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let task = || 1 + 2;

    let result = run(task);

    println!("{}", result);
}
```

But I'm getting a lifetime error I can't figure out.

```
<anon>:6:5: 6:18 error: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough [E0310]
<anon>:6     thread::spawn(move || {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:6:5: 6:18 help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
<anon>:6:5: 6:18 note: ...so that captured variable `tx` does not outlive the enclosing closure
<anon>:6     thread::spawn(move || {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:15:22: 15:26 error: mismatched types:
 expected `fn() -> _`,
    found `[closure <anon>:13:16: 13:24]`
(expected fn pointer,
    found closure) [E0308]
<anon>:15     let result = run(task);
                               ^~~~
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message suggests adding a `'static` bound to the type parameter `T`.  If you do this, it will get rid of the first error:

```
fn run<T: Send + 'static>(task: fn() -> T) -> T
```

The `'static` bound is needed to guarantee that the value returned by `task` can outlive the function where `task` runs.  [Read more about the `'static` lifetime.](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#%27static)

The second error is that you are passing a closure, while `run` expects a function pointer.  One way to fix this is by changing `task` from a closure to a fn:

```
    fn task() -> u32 { 1 + 2 }
```

Here's the complete working code:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

fn run<T: Send + 'static>(task: fn() -> T) -> T {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        tx.send(task());
    });
    rx.recv().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    fn task() -> u32 { 1 + 2 }
    let result = run(task);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I managed to work out the closure version here as well: http://is.gd/8UwpjT -- Adding `'static` always feels like a dirty choice. The docs say that it means the item will last for the life of the program. Is this bad practice? When is it acceptable to use static lifetimes?

Comment: After some experimentation, I *think* I get it... http://is.gd/8KWutk `'static` means that the given Trait is static -- not the item being passed in! This makes more sense.